# RESTful API built on top of DynamoDB?

Tags: python, api, rest, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for a super-easy way to build a RESTful API in python on top of DynamoDB.  If running on MongoDB, for example, there is [EVE](http://python-eve.org/).  Similar tools to EVE include Falcon, Tastypie, Flask-RESTful... Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, none of them work with DynamoDB out of the box.  DynamoDB is popular enough that I feel this is likely to be a solved problem already, but.. what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

**AWS API GateWay** (Rest), **Lambda** (InBetween/Logic) and **DynamoDB**(Data).

Tutorial: https://snowulf.com/2015/08/05/tutorial-aws-api-gateway-to-lambda-to-dynamodb/

*note: you can use **Python** in Lambda*